# Is it possible to get a passport stamped on entry to Canada from the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada

A follow up from [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/171885/13116), in which @Doc mentions getting a passport stamp on entry to Canada from the US. I've travelled from the US to Canada and back many times on a US passport, and I've had family members who made the same trip in reverse on a Canadian passort. None of the customs officials (US or Canadian) have ever stamped our passports, undoubtedly because of the close association between the two countries. While having the passport stamped really serves no official purpose, it might be a kind of "souvenir", especially for kids to see when they travelled.

Could I, on presenting my US passport to border control on entering Canada, ask them to stamp it?

Comment: Note that since you are a U.S. citizen, the considerations in the other question mostly don't apply to you, since you can never overstay the U.S.

Comment: True, the question here is really the last sentence: could I, on presenting my passport to border control on entering Canada, ask them to stamp it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could I, on presenting my US passport to border control on entering Canada, ask them to stamp it?

Yes. Passports are no longer routinely stamped for most visitors with the default authorized period of stay (6 months). But they will still stamp it if you ask for it nicely. You must see a border service officer for this (kiosks don't give stamps).